# To know whether my Uni can run Python web applications

Tags: mysql, database, python, mod-wsgi

I am completing [my first database project.](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1168701/to-make-a-plan-for-my-first-mysql-project)
I am going to set up [mod_wsgi](http://code.google.com/p/modwsgi/) to Apache such that I can run Python webframework on my Uni's servers. I am not sure whether my Uni has those tools or not.

My Uni gives me no support in Python and its config to their servers.

I would like to know a way to get info about the servers in the shell such that I can decide whether to use their supported tools (Oracle, PHP), or tools which I like (Python, MySQL).

**Which commands can you run to get info about the servers such that I can decide which tools to use?**

Comment: +1 just because downvotes without comments should be forbidden.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From what you've written I see no reason to rely on the uni's server. Is there any reason you can't just run this on your own machine? If not, you could just install the tools you want to use.

Comment: I did this finally :)

Answer (score 4):

If this is a uni project, I would really consult with them, not just to determine what you *can* run, but also what they *will accept* as a project deliverable.

Otherwise you could waste a lot of time working on a project that nobody is prepared to mark.

Comment: I have done that. This was their answer which I get: *I test the app on Windows, Linux or Ubuntu (I am not at the campus so I cannot check, but perhaps by Firefox).*  for my question **Which is your software and hardware support for the database project? Which tools do you use in testing the database program?** --- I need to send them more emails to get an adequate answer.

Answer (score 1):

Step 1: 
Try to call python

```
> python
or
> /usr/local/bin/python
```

Step 2:

in python call

```
> import sys
> print sys.path
```

to findout where the modules are

Step 3:
Go to the dirs listed in sys.path (via cd) and
examine the modules, search for 'mysql' and 'django'

:-(  It is possible that you have not the rights to do these steps !

Try in python :

import _mysql

import django

**if this fails:**

you can try to download django 
and install it in your home and use sqlite or oracle with django

Comment: Their Python -version is 2.5.1. Other info: [GCC 4.1.2 20070925 (Red Hat 4.1.2-33)] on linux2. I know nothing about Red Hat. Gcc seems to be a compiler.

Comment: Your last command gives me `['', '/opt/local/Library/Frameworks/Python.framework/Versions/2.6', '/home/me', '/usr/lib/python25.zip', '/usr/lib/python2.5', '/usr/lib/python2.5/plat-linux2', '/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-tk', '/usr/lib/python2.5/lib-dynload', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/Numeric', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/PIL', '/usr/lib/python2.5/site-packages/gtk-2.0']`

Comment: **What does the Python -modules tell you about the possibility of using these servers in building a Django database app?**

Comment: 1. there is a python 2.5 installaion -> good.
/ 2. go to the dirs (via cd and ls) and search for modules like _mysql and django

Comment: `import _mysql` and `import django` fail. I run unsuccessfully `import _oracle` and `import _sqlite`. --- This is strange, since my Uni has a support for Oracle and PostgreSQL. **Do you know how I can import PostgreSQL to Python?**